How can I print data received by OpenSSL SSL_read() in LLDB?
Printing outgoing data sent with SSL_write() on ARM64 is quite simple:
break set --auto-continue true -n SSL_write
break command add
    memory read -f Y -c `$x2` $x1
DONE

The signature of SSL_write() is

int SSL_write(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, int num);

and on ARM64 the first 8 registers are used to pass arguments, as long as they fit into registers, so buf is in $x1 and num is in $x2. -f Y dumps memory as a hexdump with ASCII.
But how can I print incoming data read with SSL_read()?
The signature of SSL_read() is

int SSL_read(SSL *ssl, void *buf, int num);

but the problem is that only once the function returns the read data can be found in buf and also the return value of the function tells you how many bytes have actually been read, num is just the capacity of the buffer.
I cannot break on the return of SSL_read() as this will always be at a different memory address every time the binary loads.
I tried to write break commands that use finish to first jump out of the function but that also fails for two reasons: finish stops break commands from being executed and even when I try to dump the memory manually on LLDB prompt, $x1 no longer points to the buffer after return, so I don't know the buffer address.

To dump data received by SSL_read() on ARM64, you need to run the following commands in LLDB:
expr void * $buffer = 0
break set --auto-continue true -n SSL_read
break command add
    expr $buffer = (void *)$x1
    break set --auto-continue true --one-shot true --address $x30
    break command add --stop-on-error false -o "memory read -f Y -c `$x0` $buffer"
DONE

Let's analyze what's going on here:

expr void * $buffer = 0 defines a global LLDB variable named $buffer of type void * (initial value is 0 == NULL).

break set --auto-continue true -n SSL_read sets an auto-continue breakpoint on SSL_read().

break command add adds commands to the last set breakpoint.

expr $buffer = (void *)$x1 captures the current value of register $x1, which is the buf argument, in the global $buffer variable, so we don't lose that value.

break set --auto-continue true --one-shot true --address $x30 sets a new auto-continue break point at the address found in the register $x30. $x30 is the register where ARM64 stores the return address of the current function call, so we set a breakpoint to the address where execution will continue once return has been called. Also note that this breakpoint is one shot, that means this breakpoint is deleted the moment it has been triggered.

break command add --stop-on-error false -o "memory read -f Y -c `$x0` $buffer adds a command to the dynamic breakpoint just defined above. It will dump $x0 bytes (on ARM64, the return value of a function is found in $x0 when it fits into a register) from address remembered in $buffer. Also note that this breakpoint won't stop on error. That's important, as the memory dump could fail because $x0 might be 0 (no bytes were read) or negative (there was an error reading bytes), in which case the memory dump will fail and that would otherwise cause the debugger to halt execution.


On x86_64, it depends on the calling convention. With SysV convention (Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, Solaris, etc.), it would be:
expr void * $buffer = 0
break set --auto-continue true -n SSL_read
break command add
    expr $buffer = (void *)$rsi
    break set --auto-continue true --one-shot true --address `$rip`
    break command add --stop-on-error false -o "memory read -f Y -c `$rax` $buffer"
DONE

but on Windows, replace
expr $buffer = (void *)$rsi

with
expr $buffer = (void *)$rdx

Just FYI: 
The reason why you cannot use finish or any form of stepping within breakpoint actions is because those actions are not re-entrant safe. If an action would move the instruction cursor, it could hit another breakpoint and that would break LLDB. So every time you perform any action that cause the instruction pointer to change, LLDB has to stop executing further actions of the current breakpoint.

You probably also want to make sure the breakpoint you set is thread specific (to the current thread).  If you are trying to match "the calls to SSL_read" with their output, you want to make sure you hit the breakpoint that particular SSL_read caused to be set.

@JimIngham That's a good point. In my case all network operation happened on the same thread but if an app manages multiple connections on separate threads, then you must indeed take the thread into consideration, too.

If you like Python, another slightly more abstract way to do this would be to use a scripted step plan to orchestrate the "stepping out" from SSL_read and gathering the data you want.
Here's a rough version of what you wanted to do.  In the example I had this code in /tmp/step_cmd.py...  The parts relevant to your investigation are the end of __init__ and the do_print method.  The rest is the thread plan management.
import lldb

class FinishPrintAndContinue:
    def __init__(self, thread_plan, dict):
        # Record some useful objects:
        self.thread_plan = thread_plan
        self.thread = self.thread_plan.GetThread()
        self.target = self.thread.process.target

        # Push the step out plan:
        self.step_out_thread_plan = thread_plan.QueueThreadPlanForStepOut(0, True)

        # Record the buffer value from arg2
        frame = self.thread.frames[0]
        reg_value = frame.FindRegister('arg2')
        self.buff_addr = reg_value.GetValueAsAddress()

    def is_stale(self):
        if self.step_out_thread_plan.IsPlanStale():
            self.do_print()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def explains_stop(self, event):
        return False

    def should_stop(self, event):
        if self.step_out_thread_plan.IsPlanComplete():
            self.do_print()
            self.thread_plan.SetPlanComplete(True)
        return False

    def do_print(self):
        # Fetch the return value:
        frame = self.thread.frames[0]
        num_elements = frame.FindRegister('x0').unsigned
        error = lldb.SBError()
        buffer = self.thread.process.ReadMemory(self.buff_addr, num_elements, error)
        if error.success:
            print(f"Got data:\n{buffer}")
        else:
            print(f"Error fetching buffer: {error.description}")


    def stop_description(self, stream):
        stream.Print("Stepped out of target function and read buffer")

def BreakpointCallback(frame, bp_loc, internal_dict):
    thread = frame.thread
    thread.StepUsingScriptedThreadPlan(f"{__name__}.FinishPrintAndContinue", False)
    return False

I used the convenience alias arg2 which translates to the first argument passing register on your architecture.  There isn't an alias for the "scalar return register" however, so I had to dial that up for arm64.  You'd use whatever the "scalar return register" is on your platform.
Then in lldb, do:
(lldb) command script import /tmp/step_cmd.py
(lldb) break set -n SSL_read
(lldb) break command add -s python -F step_cmd.BreakpointCallback

Note, a separate instance of the FinishPrintAndContinue class is created to handle each individual step, but the class data is shared, so if you wanted to record statistics, or store away the data you found across multiple hits of the original breakpoint, you can make some kind of class object to do that.
There's more about scripted step plans here:
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#using-the-python-api-to-create-custom-stepping-logic
and more about the lldb Python API here:
https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api.html
